# Excel thinks every number is greater than 202206

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm struggling to get Excel to determine if a value is greater than or less than.

In my table, I have column F which is a date. Column G is the following formula

```
LEFT(F2,6)
```

and this formula takes the first 6 characters from F, and sticks them onto the cell in column G, giving me year and month.

All good so far. The final part is confusing me. I want to treat the values in G as a number and compare them...

So, if the value in G is the same or greater than 202206 then it should show TRUE. If not it should be false. And from the screen shot, you can see, 202201 is not greater or equal to 202206 yet, it shows it is TRUE

Column G is formatted as `General` but even if I change it `Number` or `Accounting` the same issue persists

I also tried the following (didn't help)

```
= IF(G2 >= 202206)
```

Nor did

```
=IF(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(G2,6))> 202206, "Y","N")
```

[image]

Comment: It could be that the column is formatted as TEXT.

Comment: @patkim good shout, I forgot to mention I had tried making G Number of accounting - same issue

Comment: what if you use VALUE function on that column, in your formula? It will convert valid numeric text to actual Number format. E.g. =VALUE(D3)>=202206

Comment: Please check if this is your case --> https://i.imgur.com/vlgBnbF.png

Comment: Hmmm - I think the file is corrupted or some strange formatting because I re-downloaded the original report, did the same thing, and it's working fine

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions To be honest, I’ve been getting more “flighty” behavior from Excel the last year or so.  I spend a lot of time in excel, and often with fairly complicated worksheets, and I find myself more and more having to exit and re-open.  I fear that the rich feature set we’ve been given in dynamic areas, etc. have come at the cost of some stability.

Comment: I have always found your better off using the trim function.  LEFT(trim(F2),6)  Frequently, a space or other white space character sneaks in and messes you up.

Answer (score 0):

Text functions always return text. To convert to a number, use a mathematical operation such as double negative.

=IF(--LEFT(G2,6)> 202206, "Y","N")